# Reflection Based Instantiations

Tags: reflection

When is it desired to have reflection based instantiation instead of a normal instantiation via a new? Is it a good software engineering practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reflection is required when your program does not have a compile-time access to the class, for example, when the class is provided in a library at run-time, and the name of the class and the path to the library are provided to your program as part of configuration. Independently developed plug-ins for your program are good candidates for reflection-based instantiation. Reflection-based instantiation may be desirable in other cases as well: for example, when you know which classes you want, but you do not know ahead of time in what way you want them to be connected. Constructing expression trees is an example of this situation.